# Decrease headings automatically while inserting to main document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have document with headings and generated table of content. I need to place hughe another document with headings like anex for main document.

```
main document:

Heading1 Title
 Heading2 SubTitle
Heading1 Anex 1


document to insert:

Heading1 TitleDocIns
 Heading2 SubTitleDocIns
```

I need headings of main document to be decreased while inserting into Anex 1 of main document and as result will get something like:

```
Heading1 Title
 Heading2 SubTitle
Heading1 Anex 1
 Heading2 TitleDocIns
  Heading3 SubTitleDocIns
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Easiest to just do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with find - replace:

In the original document, before pasting it to the other one (save it to a temporary location if you want to prevent changes in the original copy):

- press CTRL+H
- Select "use wildcards" (if you don't see that option, then press "more")
- in "find what" enter: `*^13` (0 or more characters and line break), then click format - style and select the last heading style used (e.g. heading 3)
- in "replace to" enter `^&` (find what text), then again click format - style and select the style you want to change previous one to (e.g. heading 2)
- press replace all
- do it for all styles up to heading 1

[image]